# How to Close Profit without calculating the lowest open position (for buy) & highest open position (for Sell)?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, trading, mql4, metatrader4, forex

[image]

I manage to get the highest,closeall and profit..cant get the lowest..
for lowest can we use the MathMin(lowest, OrderOpenPrice())?
still stuck how to close by remaining the highest(sell) and lowest(buy) open position

```
double HighestOpenPrice(int m)
{
   double highest=0;
   for(int i=OrdersTotal()-1; i>=0; i--)
   {
      if(!OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES))
         continue;
      if(OrderType()==m && m==0 && OrderType()==OP_BUY && OrderSymbol()==Symbol() && OrderMagicNumber() == MagicNumber)
         highest=MathMax(highest, OrderOpenPrice());
      if(OrderType()==m && m==1 && OrderType()==OP_SELL && OrderSymbol()==Symbol() && OrderMagicNumber() == MagicNumber)
         highest=MathMax(highest, OrderOpenPrice());
   }
   return(highest);
}
```

```
double TotalOpenProfit(int direction)
{
   double result = 0;
   for(int i=OrdersTotal()-1; i>=0; i--)  
   {
      if(!OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES)) continue;
      if(OrderSymbol() != Symbol() || OrderMagicNumber() != MagicNumber) continue;
      if((direction < 0 && OrderType() == OP_BUY) || (direction > 0 && OrderType() == OP_SELL)) continue;
      result += OrderProfit()+OrderSwap()+OrderCommission();
   }
   return(result);
}
```

```
bool CustomCloseAll(int m)
{
   int ticket=0;
   for(int i = OrdersTotal()-1; i>=0; i--)
   {
      if(!OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES))continue;
         
      if(OrderType()==m && m==0 && OrderType()==OP_BUY && OrderSymbol()==Symbol())
         ticket= OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), MarketInfo(OrderSymbol(), MODE_BID), 3, CLR_NONE);
         
      if(OrderType()==m && m==1 && OrderType()==OP_SELL && OrderSymbol()==Symbol())
         ticket= OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), MarketInfo(OrderSymbol(), MODE_ASK), 3, CLR_NONE);
   }
   if(!OrdersTotal())break;
}
```

Comment: Why you checking `OrderType()` in your `CustomCloseAll` function triple times ? In case of **sell** order, `OrderType()==OP_SELL` is enough, look at the docs: [OrderType enums](https://docs.mql4.com/constants/tradingconstants/orderproperties), [OrderType](https://docs.mql4.com/trading/ordertype)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without iterating over all orders. If in your strategy, the **latest** order has the highest price in case of **buy** or the lowest in case of **sell**, you can simply assign the ticket number to the global variable when sending a new order. For example:

```
//Global variables
int lastSellTicket = 0; 
int lastBuyTicket = 0;
```

and on order send case (e.g. **sell**)

```
int ticket = OrderSend(Symbol(), OP_SELL, lot, Bid, 0, 0, 0, "Sell", magic);
if(ticket > 0) {
    lastSellTicket = ticket;
}
else{
    Print("Error send order. Error code: ", GetLastError());
}
```

If it's not the latest order (but the highest/lowest price), you can do the same but additionally before order send case, use comparison between the highest/lowest `OrderOpenPrice()` and the current open price.
Example (**buy**):

```
double lastBuyOpenPrice = -1;
if(OrderSelect(lastBuyTicket, SELECT_BY_TICKET)){
    lastBuyOpenPrice = OrderOpenPrice();
}
int ticket = OrderSend(Symbol(), OP_BUY, lot, Ask, 0, 0, 0, "Buy", magic);
if(ticket > 0 ) {
    if(Ask > lastBuyOpenPrice ){ //If current open price is greater than the latest one
        lastBuyTicket = ticket;
    }
}
else{
    Print("Error send order. Error code: ", GetLastError());
}
```

And then, in your `TotalOpenProfit` and `CustomCloseAll` function add logic for avoid calculating/closing those latest orders:

```
if(OrderTicket() != lastSellTicket || OrderTicket() != lastBuyTicket){
    //your logic...
}
```